# What does the badge on the Store icon in the Messages app indicate?

Tags: ios, messages, ios-appstore

The Store icon of my iPhone's Messages app has been displaying this red badge for as far back as I can remember.

[image: red badge displaying number on Messages' Store icon]

When I open the Messages App Store, I can't find any updates or new information that the badge might relate to.

The only tip I got from people so far was that it might be related to pending updates of apps that provide stickers; I have made sure to bring all apps on my iPhone up to date, but the badge persists.

What does the badge on the Store icon indicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badge indicates the count of iMessage apps that can be enabled. This appears after you have installed an iOS app(s) with iMessage counterpart available.

[image] [image]

Image Source: Apple Discussion Forums